# multi line tag in grails or html

Tags: grails, input, textarea, indentation

With a grails app and from a local database, I'm returning some text in a xml format.

I can return it well formed in a `<textarea></textarea>` tag with the correct indenting (tabulation, line return,...etc.)

I want to go a bit further. In the text I'm returning, there are some `<img/>` tags and I'd like to replace those tag by the real images themselves.

I searched around and found no solution as of now. I understood that you can't add an image to a textarea (other then in a background), and if I choose a div tag, I won't have the indenting anymore (and therefore, harder to read)

I was wondering if using a `<g:textField/>` or an other tag from the grails library will do the trick. And if so, How can I append them to a page using jquery.

For example, how to append a `<g:textField/>` in jquery. It doesn't interpret it and I get this error

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list [Break On This Error]...+doc).append("<input type="text" id="FTMAP_&quot;+nb_sec+&quot;" ...
```

And in my javascript file, I have

```
$("#FTM_"+doc).append("<g:textField id='FTMAP_"+nb_sec+"' ... />
```

Any possible solutions ?

EDIT

I did forget to mention that my final intentions are to be able to modify the text (tags included) and to have a nice and neat indentation so that it is the easiest possible for the end user.

Comment: `<g:textField/>` don't do the trick, it's `<input type="text">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking a few different questions:

*1. Can I use a single HTML tag to include images inside pre-formatted text.*

No. You will have to parse the text and translate it into styled text yourself.

*2. Is there a tag in the grails standard tags to accomplish this for me?*

No.

*3. How can I add grails tags from my javascript code.*

Grails tags are processed on the server-side, and javascript is processed on the client. This means you cannot directly add grails tags via javascript.

There are a couple methods that can accomplish the same result, however:

- You can set a javascript variable to the rendered content of a grails tag. This solution is good for data that is known at the time of the initial request.

  `var tagOutput = "${g.textField(/* etc */)}";`
- You can make an ajax request for the content to be added. Then your server-side grails code can render the tags you need. This is better for realtime data, or data that will be updated more than once on a single rendered page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was looking in a WYSIWYG solution but it doesn't seem to work out. For what I want, I going to work the text myself then. Thanks for the 3rd tip, will surely come in handy !